# Change an image that is store in parse through android

Tags: java, android, button, parse-platform, android-imageview

I am trying to update an image that is saved in parse through the android app, I am able o retrieve it and load it to the app but I am not able to save the new image that I selected to replace the old one. This is how I tried to do it and it only saves the file on the current state and not to parse. This is the code that I have currently and it is not working the way I want it to. Kindly assist.

Code is as follows

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS) {
                Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
                InputStream inputStream;
                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(pickedImage);
                    Bitmap selectedImages = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    imageSelected.setImageBitmap(selectedImages);

                        selectedImages = ((BitmapDrawable) imageSelected.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        selectedImages.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 5, stream);

                        byte[] imageRec = stream.toByteArray();
                        file = new ParseFile("profileUpdate.png", imageRec);

                        file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (null == e)
                                    currentUser.put("ProfilePicture", file);
                            }
                        });
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unable to load image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the currentUser.saveInBackground(); line after currentUser.put("ProfilePicture", file); and added a currentUser.remove("ProfilePicture"); before it and it worked.